# Modal background overflowing

Tags: html, css

[Current Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTHPK.png)
Modal Background keeps overflowing over the container

```
    .modal-content {
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            max-width: 80%;
            text-align: center;
            position: relative;
            color: #000; 
        }
        
        /* Modal styles */
        .modal-container {
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            background-color: #fff;
            z-index: 1;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            max-width: 80%;
            max-height: 80%; 
            overflow-y: auto; 
            text-align: center;
            color: #000; 
            max-height: 80vh;
        }

        .close-button {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            right: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
            color: #000; 
        }
```

Thats what the code looks like ive tried limiting however nothing has worked. The other thing I tried was changing the entire modal in html however nothing has worked for me if someone can help that would be great.

Comment: we're missing the HTML code of yours. Try reproducing the case in https://codepen.io/ and sending the link